# Count/Enumerate files in folder filtered by content

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a folder with lots of files with some data. Not every file has a complete data set.
The complete data sets all have a common string of the form 'yyyy-mm-dd' on the last line so i thought i might filter with something like `tail -n 1`, but have no idea how to do that.

Any idea how to do something like that in a simple script or bash command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in *
do
    tail -n 1 "$f" |
    grep -qE '^[0-9]{4}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]$' &&
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Sounds good. What if I'm looking for a specific string instead of a general one?

Comment: replace the grep line with : grep "SPECIFIC STRING"